# assign name to php object at runtime

Tags: php

i want to select attendance details of an employee on the basis of months selected. i want to store data of each month with object name same as month. i don't understand how to assign name at run time. here is my code given below

```
 for ($i=0; $i < $totalmonth; $i++) { 


  $query="SELECT attendance FROM attendance
    WHERE month='$m' && year='$y' && dept='$dept' && location='$loc'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
      {
          $dbdata = array();
          while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())
          {
               array_push($dbdata, $row);
          }
       }
    else
      {
         echo 'Data Not Found';
      }
         echo json_encode(array('data' => $dbdata));

    }
```

Comment: You want this "Jan"=>data of jan??

Answer (score 1):

Use associative array to assign name of month as key in the code just like below;

```
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
     $dbdata[$m]=$row;  
}
```